# Binary integer programming problem of a very specific form

Tags: linear-programming

The specificity of the problem lies in the fact that the objective function coincides with the left side of the only constraint. In other words:

$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x_i \to \max,
$$
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x_i \leq C,
$$
$$
a_i\in\mathbb{R}, x_i\in\{0,1\}, C\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Note that $a_i$ are real. Could you recommend the best method to solve this type of problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems) for the case when profits and weights coincide.

Comment: You are welcome.